# Hidden Review Tasks

Tags: support, bug

Anytime I'm on the Salesforce portion of Stack exchange, it shows me with 10-11 review tasks at the top of the screen to complete.

[image]

I then click on the Number (or review since they take me to the same place) and it doesn't show me with any valid review tasks:

[image]

Is the number showing me something incorrect or is there another section I don't know about to review with?

Comment: I think it's a bug in the latest page design (from a few months ago). I think they had to fix something for the normal review queues, and possibly forgot to fix it for the site evaluation queue.

Comment: My observation has been that until the review items clear the queue, the number seems to remain there. For example if it takes 5 ppl to close an item, until it gets closed, it remains visible in the number for review. Example being the Self-Eval since it's not done yet, it always appears until closed. Again, just an observation. Within 24 hrs, it always gets reset if not sooner. Agree with Samuel though that its a bug, not a feature.

Comment: I haven't seen the number less than 10 in about 2-3 months is the weird part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this weekend those numbers went away.  I have no explanation as to why it no longer has them.

Comment: Yup, as of today, once I vote on something I can confirm that its completely disappearing here too. Yay! :)